# posix_kill is not working from cli

Tags: php, process, signals, posix

here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  $pid = 18283; 
  $is_ok = posix_kill($pid, SIGKILL);
  if($is_ok){
    echo 'OK';
  } else {
    echo 'NOT OK';
  }
```

Script output is 'NOT OK', process with pid 18283 still exists. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You will only be able to kill processes that you own, is the pid given owned by the same user that is running the script. Try checking posix_get_last_error() to see why it is failing

Comment: @Anigel yes, and i can kill process manually by kill from console